# where clause on non-indexed column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table where id is its primary key. It contains five hundred thousand or even more rows and there are only less than ten fired employees. What is the best way to look them up?

```
SELECT id, name, mode
  FROM employees
  WHERE mode   = 'fired'
```

table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(27,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [mode] [varchar](45) NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create NON CLUSTERED conditional index.

```
 CREATE NON CLUSTERED INDEX ix_employees_firedEmployees ON employees (name) INCLUDE (mode) WHERE mode = 'fired';
```

But in practice better way to have flags or status to indicate such employees. For example status CHAR(1) = 'F', or IsFired BIT = 1

Answer (score 2):

As sidux said, you should create an index on the mode column.

Adding more options to sidux answer, In my opinion, you should have another table with metadata information about the status of the employee and have a FK to that table as Status of the employee, replacing the mode column (id, name, statusId). This will allow you to create a smaller index and with that getting a better performance when filtering by status id (with index created)